# factor level dropped in glmer results

Tags: r, glm, lme4, mixed-models

This being my same question [missing level in glmer summary output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342269/missing-level-in-glmer-summary-output),
is a way to tell R not to use a factor level as a default and\or to select one level as default instead?

Comment: I think it's better to include all the necessary details in a single question. Otherwise, maybe ask everything in the linked question? [See here for details on how to better formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Perhaps what you are referring to is the fact that R uses factor levels alphabetically?  So the one that is 'missing' starts with the letter that is closest to 'A', and is included in the intercept. You can easily change this by renaming variables to be something like "A_variableName", but that isn't the prettiest solution.